# Showing $\frac16 \tan^6x +\frac18\tan^8x = \frac14 \cos^{-4}x -\frac13 \cos^{-6}x + \frac18\cos^{-8}x+c$ for some real $c$, without calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

While teaching my calculus class I happened upon a strange identity. Consider the antiderivative $$\int \tan^5 x \sec^4 x dx.$$
You can do that by writing the integrand as $\tan^5 x (1+\tan^2 x) \sec^2x$, then substituting $u=\tan x$. This gives one answer.

But another way to do it is to rewrite the integrand as $\sin^5 x \cos^{-9} x = \sin x (1-\cos^2 x)^2 \cos^{-9}x$, then apply a substitution $u=\cos x$.

If you follow through with both of these methods, it seems to give the strange identity $$\frac16 \tan^6x +\frac18\tan^8x = \frac14 \cos^{-4}x -\frac13 \cos^{-6}x + \frac18\cos^{-8}x+c,$$ for some $c\in \Bbb R$. I didn't believe it at first, but a student checked it on desmos and they seem to agree.

**Questions:** Is there a simple way to see that without calculus?

And is there some general way to generate these kinds of seemingly nontrivial trig identities, where some function of tangent equals some other function of sine/cosine?

I thought maybe it could be related to some orthogonal polynomial families like Chebyshev polynomials etc, but it's unclear.

Comment: You can verify this by using $tan^2(x) = sec^2(x) - 1$ (and of course $sec(x) = cos(x)^{-1}$) to get everything in terms of secant. I got $c=-1/24$.

Comment: Oh you are right, any even powers of tangent can be expanded into some polynomial of sec^2(x), nothing beyond that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just binomial expansion applied to the identity
$$\sec^2 x = 1 + \tan^2 x.$$
We have
$$\begin{align}
\sec^4 x &= 1 + 2 \tan^2 x + \tan^4 x \\
\sec^6 x &= 1 + 3 \tan^2 x + 3 \tan^4 x + \tan^6 x \\
\sec^8 x &= 1 + 4 \tan^2 x + 6 \tan^4 x + 4 \tan^6 x + \tan^8 x
\end{align}$$
hence
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4} \sec^4 x - \frac{1}{3} \sec^6 x + \frac{1}{8} \sec^8 x
&= A + B \tan^2 x + C \tan^4 x + D \tan^6 x + E \tan^8 x
\end{align}$$
where
$$\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{24} \\
B &= \frac{2}{4} - \frac{3}{3} + \frac{4}{8} = 0 \\
C &= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{3}{3} + \frac{6}{8} = 0 \\
D &= -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{6} \\
E &= \frac{1}{8},
\end{align}$$
and the result immediately follows with the constant term equal to $A = \frac{1}{24}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{4} \sec ^4 x-\frac{1}{3} \sec ^6 x+\frac{1}{8} \sec ^8 x \\
= & \frac{\sec ^4 x}{24}\left(6-8 \sec ^2 x+3 \sec ^4 x\right) \\
= & \frac{\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)^2}{24}\left[6-8\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)+3\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)^2\right] \\
= & \frac{\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)^2}{24}\left(3 \tan ^4 x-2 \tan ^2 x+1\right) \\
= & \frac{\tan ^6 x}{6}+\frac{\tan ^8 x}{8}+\frac{1}{24}
\end{aligned}
$$